# Average of a NSArray and store value in a new NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, average

i would like to have the average of my NSArray element and store them in a new array in the following way.

```
NSArray* number;
NSMutableArray* Average;

[Average objectAtIndex:0]=[number objectAtIndex:0];
[Average objectAtIndex:1]=([number objectAtIndex:0] + [number objectAtIndex:1])/2;
[Average objectAtIndex:2]=([number objectAtIndex:0] + [number objectAtIndex:1] + [number objectAtIndex:2])/3;
```

i was thinking of doing it using 2 for loops

```
for (int i =0; i<[number count]; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
    temp+=[number objectAtIndex:j];
  }

[Average addObject: temp/(i+1)];

}
```

can anyone help me with a more efficient way

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need one loop:

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@(2.4), @(2.7), @(4.0)];
NSMutableArray *averages = [NSMutableArray array];
double total = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < [numbers count]; i++) {
    total += [[numbers objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
    [averages addObject:@(total / (i + 1))];
}
```

or, using fast enumeration:

```
__block double total = 0.0;

[numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *number, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    total += [number doubleValue];
    [averages addObject:@(total / (idx + 1))];
}];
```

By the way, unrelated to your question, but if you simply wanted to average all the numbers in the `numbers` array, you could use [KVC collection operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html):

```
NSNumber *average = [numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
```

Clearly that's only useful if you wanted to average all the numbers in the array, but it's a convenient shorthand in those situations.

Comment: KVO is unquestionably the most succinct way to do that ;)